# What is a possible way to make game graphics for Corona SDK?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, cross-platform, coronasdk

I have been developing a simple iPhone/Android game with Corona SDK.  The game itself does not use imported graphics, only regular shapes.  Now, I am faced with the problem of making the graphics for the title-screen, end-screen and buttons.  I just need to know a possible way to do this.  If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be really great,if you could provide us with the code and tell us what you have tried so far , and what is the issue your facing right now.

Comment: tbh, I understand this like we are ment to answer "A possible way is to photoshop images and use them in your application"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean, could you give some examples?

Maybe this?

```
local options = {
    defaultFile = image_path,
    overFile = image_path_o,
    onRelease = function ()
        --code here
    end
}

local img_button = widget.newButton(options)
```